# Как написать скрипт

Tags: bash

у меня есть файл в котором такие данные:

```
128.124.53.81 - - [17/May/2021:19:41:50 +0300] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2018/11/baner_PNU_1550x400-e1569401806743.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 151360 "https://x.x.x/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/87.0.4280.163 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"<br>
```

Как вывести в другой файл все записи между часами 21:40 и 22:00

Answer (score -1):

Примерно так:

```
grep -P '\[17\/May\/2021:21:[45]\d:\d{2}\s\+0300\]' filename > anotherfile
```